# Use AJAX to Pull PHP Session into JS

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to use a variable within some JS. I understand how to execute a PHP session via AJAX, but I need to pull a PHP Session for use within the JS.

Can anyone help point out how I might be able to fix the code below to show an alert of whatever is currently set as the $_SESSION['variaible'];

Thank you!

session.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['variable'] = "true";
?>
```

download.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function closeDownload()
{
   session_start();
   $variable = $_SESSION['variable'];

   $.get("session.php")   
   alert("<?php echo "$variable"; ?>");
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="close_download.php" data-role="button" onClick="closeDownload()">Close</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are mixing up php and javascript. please make sure you know what you are doing first. :)

Comment: Do you actually know that php is executed on the server and JS in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way.

```
 <?php

   session_start();
   $_SESSION['variable']="mysession";
?>
<html>
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function closeDownload()
{
   alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['variable']; ?>");
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-role="button" onClick="closeDownload()">Close</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it would be something along the lines of:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<head>
    <script>
        function closeDownload()
        {

               var variable = <?php echo $_SESSION['variable']; ?>;

               alert(variable);
        }
    </script>

</head>
```

PHP is separate from JS, but you can 'echo' to javascript from PHP the same way you would normally do with HTML. Remember that `session_start` has to be the first thing ever in your code, as it sets some headers.

Answer (score 0):

**Option one:**

You directly access the variable in the php file.

1. Rename file download.html to download.php.
2. variable = `<?php echo $_SESSION['variable']; ?>`

**Option two:**

You make a ajax call to get the value from a php file

1. Create a file getsession.php
2. `<?php echo $_SESSION['variable']; ?>`
3. Make a ajax call to this page.